# Is the wave, as described by Schrödingers equation, itself the cause of the gravitation's curvature of space time?

Tags: gravity, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, curvature, quantum-gravity

Considering a one-dimensional inelastic string that is tensioned from its ends, wouldn't both ends of the string have to be pulled inward when it is rippled by a wave? Wouldn't the same be true in a three-dimensional universe where matter is represented by waves (of cause ignoring the probabilistic interpretation of the Schrödinger equation)?

Answer (score 1):

Spacetime is curved in general relativity, where there are no matter waves.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good suggestion, and indeed making a string vibrate does increase the tension in the string, and the greater the amplitude of the vibration the greater the increase in the tension. If the wave function were a vibration of space in the same way that a string vibrates it could plausibly have the effect you suggest.

However the wave function is not like a vibration on a string. In fact the name is somewhat misleading as many wave functions are not waves at all. For example the 1s, 2s, etc orbitals of the hydrogen atom are wave functions but don't even remotely resemble waves.

The wave function is best thought of as a mathematical object that encodes all the information about the system. That is, anything we could measure about the system can be obtained from its wave function. However we cannot measure the wave function itself, and indeed it's not at all obvious that it makes sense to consider the wave function as some physical object.

Comment: Yes, that's true, of course. Indeed, Nick from the Science Asylum YT channel explained that distinction pretty well, suggesting that the Schrödinger equation is actually the heat equation applied to quantum particles. Nevertheless, both the wave equation and the Schrödinger equation contain a curvature term, implying that there should be some form of tensioning, shouldn't there?

Comment: @LukasMolzberger The amplitude of the wave function is not a displacement in the way the amplitude of the displacement of a wave on a string is a displacement. There is simply no comparison between them. The second derivative of the wave function (is this what you mean by _curvature_?) is related to the energy, and the energy density contributes to the curvature of spacetime and hence to gravity. However this is not a direct connection and any analogy with a string is misleading.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was referring to. Thanks for the clarification.